# Sum up numeric object properties results in NaN

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object like this:

```
{id: 1, planningVerId: 1, planningVersion: null, p1: 0, p2: 0, p3: 0, p4: 45, p5: 55, p6: 0, p7: 0,…}
```

Up to `p12`. 
Later in the code I add a `sum` property to the object. Now, I would like to sum up the `p1-p12` values like this:

```
for (const prop in result) {
          if (prop.startsWith('p') && prop.length <= 3) { result.sum += Number(result[prop]) };
        }
```

I checked it with the console, I get the right values, but the result is `NaN`. 
**Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.sum` is undefined in the beginning. So `result.sum + 3` gives `NaN`:

```js
let result =  {}
result.sum += 1
console.log(result.sum);
```

Set `result.sum = 0` before the loop and it should work.

Comment: Indeed. I commented out the code, where I add the 'sum' property to the object and of course in this case it was undefined.